# QGIS how to use source query builder to only show the top X values of an attribute?

Tags: qgis, expression, query-builder

I have a layer containing polygons, and one of the attributes within it represents population growth. My goal is to filter the layer to display only the polygons with the highest 100 values of population growth.

I am considering utilizing the query builder to craft an expression, although I am uncertain about the correct expression to employ.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

If it is not possible directly in the filter query you can:

Calculate a new integer field named topx as

```sql
case 
    when 
    array_contains(array:=
    array_slice(array:=
                array_agg(expression:=$id, 
                order_by:="population"),
                start_pos:=-9, end_pos:=-1),
                value:=$id) then 1
    else 0
end
```

For the top 10 values it will get the value 1, else 0. Then filter by topx field.

You can also create a Virtual Layer:

```sql
select *
from Refactored
order by population desc
limit 10
```

[image]

A third option is to set a filter using pyqgis:

Adjust the first three lines:

```py
layername = "Grid" #The name of your layer
valuecolumn = "population" #The name of your column with values
top_n = 10 #Top 10 highest values will be filtered

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0] #Create a layer object

#Create a list of lists where each sublist is [feature id, value]
all_features = [[f.id(), f[valuecolumn]] for f in layer.getFeatures()]
#[[1, 28], [2, 369], [3, 366], [4, 393]... #feature 1 has value 28, 2 369 ...

all_features.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) #Sort by second (index 1) value in the list of lists above

#Now the list is sorted by the value attribute from highest to lowest
#[94, 988], [49, 985], [40, 970], [13, 968], ...

toplist = [item[0] for item in all_features[:top_n]] #Extract the ids of the top_n features
#[94, 49, 40, 13, 36, ...]

#Set the filter
subsetstring = f"$id IN{tuple(toplist)}" #'$id IN(94, 49, 40, 13, 36, 107, 75, 85, 54, 78)'
layer.setSubsetString(subsetstring)
```

[image]

Comment: Using a virtual layer is the best way in my opinion, the filter tool does pretty much that, defining only a WHERE clause for a SQL query for the layer. Using a query layer through the DB manager or simply through symbology should work best.